How to remove residual user and group fwupd-refresh after purging fwupd from Linux Mint 21.3?
I have removed fwupd from my system by running:
sudo apt-get purge 'fwupd*'


I am unsure why, but there seem to be some residual user & group named fwupd-refresh.
$ id fwupd-refresh
uid=128(fwupd-refresh) gid=141(fwupd-refresh) groups=141(fwupd-refresh)

$ members fwupd-refresh
fwupd-refresh

I know there are commands like groupdel and usermod and possibly others as well.
But as I almost never use such commands, I would like to ask as follows:
If it is safe to delete that user + group, what exact procedure do you recommend on doing so?
Thank you in advance!
PS: An example of residual files owned by this user & group:
$ ll /var/cache/fwupdmgr/fwupd/
total 728K
-rw-r--r-- 1 fwupd-refresh fwupd-refresh 724K 2021-Jul-31 lvfs-metadata.xml.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 fwupd-refresh fwupd-refresh  488 2021-Jul-31 lvfs-metadata.xml.gz.asc

